# scrollview for part of tablelayout in android

Tags: android, scrollview, tablelayout

I want to scroll some rows of tablelayout in android. But when I tried to take a new table layout for that particular row, it is still not scrolling that new table. And I want to do that via xml file not from java code. I am using android 4.0.3. Please Help.

Comment: it'll be easier to understand your problem if you post your code as well.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding the question you want to have some cells of a table that can scroll their contents horizontally. I was having the same issue. It seems to be caused by the table being happy to be wider than the screen, so the horizontal scroll view is allowed to be wide enough to encompass all it's content, meaning it doesnt need to scroll.

I solved the issue by programmatically setting the width on the horizontal scroll view so that it wouldnt go off the screen.